# Rails devise+omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth

I am trying to implement login from google in my rails app.I am following instructions from README file at github page of the "omniauth-google-oauth2" [LINK](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).I am trying to use the name parameter in devise.rb config file so that links are from "google" and not "google_oauth2".
So i  have added:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET", { name: "google" }
```

But in the bottom links of devise views the link is still

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2
```

but clicking on this link gives

```
Not found. Authentication passthru.
```

on page.
But now

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google
```

works.How do i fix the link?

Answer (score 2):

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 
                "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", 
                "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET", 
                { name: "google" }
```

Works just fine to change the provider name. 2 caveats

1. Change it everywhere!  Make sure your callback is using `google`, make sure your callback URL (in the google developer console) uses `google`
2. Restart your server - because it's in an initializer, any changes you've made won't be activated until you restart

Test App:
https://github.com/trh/devise_omniauth_google

Comment: It behaves this way after restart...i have changes it in devise.rb initializer, callback controller(def google...)

Comment: very strange - I'm using the same setup.  Have you made any changes to the shared links file?  Also, what versions are you using  (ruby, rails, devise, omniauth)

Comment: nope, but i have imported devise views for modification....but haven't modified shared links file...Using omniauth-google-oauth2 0.4.0...Using devise 3.5.6...ruby 2.3.0p0...Using omniauth-oauth2 1.4.0

Comment: Hmm.. I made a test app to verify -- and it worked, updated to your versions still works.  Can you try using localtest.me:3000 instead of localhost and then change your callback in the google dev console?

Comment: can't find a good reason for devise to NOT properly set the app links.. but you can feel free to take a look at my test app